Rails 7 and PostgreSQL - ILIKE not work with multilingual characters in table
I need to build a multilingual Rails 7 and PostgreSQL application. But I can’t work with ILIKE in PostgreSQL:
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test_character (
  c_name varchar(45) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO test_character VALUES ('Кириллица');
INSERT INTO test_character VALUES ('English');

SELECT * 
FROM test_character
WHERE c_name ILIKE '%кириллица%';
    
No Results

SELECT * 
FROM test_character
WHERE c_name ILIKE '%english%';
    
| c0      |
| ------- |
| English |


My config
Gemfile
...
gem "rails", "~> 7.1.3"
gem 'pg', '~> 1.5', '>= 1.5.4'
...

SHOW SERVER_ENCODING;




c0




UTF8



select datname, pg_encoding_to_char(encoding) from pg_database;




c0
c1




test_bootstrap_app_development
UTF8


test_bootstrap_app_test
UTF8


postgres
UTF8


template0
UTF8


template1
UTF8


this_is_ad_development
UTF8


this_is_ad_test
UTF8


this_is_ad_test-5
UTF8


this_is_ad_test-3
UTF8


this_is_ad_test-2
UTF8


this_is_ad_test-6
UTF8


this_is_ad_test-0
UTF8


this_is_ad_test-4
UTF8


this_is_ad_test-1
UTF8


this_is_ad_test-7
UTF8


test_ch
UTF8



$ psql -l

                                    List of databases
              Name              | Owner | Encoding | Collate | Ctype | Access privileges 
--------------------------------+-------+----------+---------+-------+-------------------
 postgres                       | nick  | UTF8     | C       | C     | 
 template0                      | nick  | UTF8     | C       | C     | =c/nick          +
                                |       |          |         |       | nick=CTc/nick
 template1                      | nick  | UTF8     | C       | C     | nick=CTc/nick    +
                                |       |          |         |       | =c/nick
 test_bootstrap_app_development | nick  | UTF8     | C       | C     | 
 test_bootstrap_app_test        | nick  | UTF8     | C       | C     | 
 test_ch                        | nick  | UTF8     | C       | C     | 
 this_is_ad_development         | nick  | UTF8     | C       | C     | 
 this_is_ad_test                | nick  | UTF8     | C       | C     | 
 this_is_ad_test-0              | nick  | UTF8     | C       | C     | 
:...skipping...

$ locale -a
en_NZ
nl_NL.UTF-8
pt_BR.UTF-8
fr_CH.ISO8859-15
eu_ES.ISO8859-15
en_US.US-ASCII
af_ZA
bg_BG
cs_CZ.UTF-8
fi_FI
zh_CN.UTF-8
eu_ES
sk_SK.ISO8859-2
nl_BE
fr_BE
sk_SK
en_US.UTF-8
en_NZ.ISO8859-1
de_CH
sk_SK.UTF-8
de_DE.UTF-8
am_ET.UTF-8
zh_HK
be_BY.UTF-8
uk_UA
pt_PT.ISO8859-1
en_AU.US-ASCII
kk_KZ.PT154
en_US
nl_BE.ISO8859-15
de_AT.ISO8859-1
hr_HR.ISO8859-2
fr_FR.ISO8859-1
af_ZA.UTF-8
am_ET
fi_FI.ISO8859-1
ro_RO.UTF-8
af_ZA.ISO8859-15
en_NZ.UTF-8
fi_FI.UTF-8
hr_HR.UTF-8
da_DK.UTF-8
ca_ES.ISO8859-1
en_AU.ISO8859-15
ro_RO.ISO8859-2
de_AT.UTF-8
pt_PT.ISO8859-15
sv_SE
fr_CA.ISO8859-1
fr_BE.ISO8859-1
en_US.ISO8859-15
it_CH.ISO8859-1
en_NZ.ISO8859-15
en_AU.UTF-8
de_AT.ISO8859-15
af_ZA.ISO8859-1
hu_HU.UTF-8
et_EE.UTF-8
he_IL.UTF-8
uk_UA.KOI8-U
be_BY
kk_KZ
hu_HU.ISO8859-2
it_CH
pt_BR
ko_KR
it_IT
fr_BE.UTF-8
ru_RU.ISO8859-5
zh_TW
zh_CN.GB2312
no_NO.ISO8859-15
de_DE.ISO8859-15
en_CA
fr_CH.UTF-8
sl_SI.UTF-8
uk_UA.ISO8859-5
pt_PT
hr_HR
cs_CZ
fr_CH
he_IL
zh_CN.GBK
zh_CN.GB18030
fr_CA
pl_PL.UTF-8
ja_JP.SJIS
sr_YU.ISO8859-5
be_BY.CP1251
sr_YU.ISO8859-2
sv_SE.UTF-8
sr_YU.UTF-8
de_CH.UTF-8
sl_SI
pt_PT.UTF-8
ro_RO
en_NZ.US-ASCII
ja_JP
zh_CN
fr_CH.ISO8859-1
ko_KR.eucKR
be_BY.ISO8859-5
nl_NL.ISO8859-15
en_GB.ISO8859-1
en_CA.US-ASCII
is_IS.ISO8859-1
ru_RU.CP866
nl_NL
fr_CA.ISO8859-15
sv_SE.ISO8859-15
hy_AM
en_CA.ISO8859-15
en_US.ISO8859-1
zh_TW.Big5
ca_ES.UTF-8
ru_RU.CP1251
en_GB.UTF-8
en_GB.US-ASCII
ru_RU.UTF-8
eu_ES.UTF-8
es_ES.ISO8859-1
hu_HU
el_GR.ISO8859-7
en_AU
it_CH.UTF-8
en_GB
sl_SI.ISO8859-2
ru_RU.KOI8-R
nl_BE.UTF-8
et_EE
fr_FR.ISO8859-15
cs_CZ.ISO8859-2
lt_LT.UTF-8
pl_PL.ISO8859-2
fr_BE.ISO8859-15
is_IS.UTF-8
tr_TR.ISO8859-9
da_DK.ISO8859-1
lt_LT.ISO8859-4
lt_LT.ISO8859-13
zh_TW.UTF-8
bg_BG.CP1251
el_GR.UTF-8
be_BY.CP1131
da_DK.ISO8859-15
is_IS.ISO8859-15
no_NO.ISO8859-1
nl_NL.ISO8859-1
nl_BE.ISO8859-1
sv_SE.ISO8859-1
pt_BR.ISO8859-1
zh_CN.eucCN
it_IT.UTF-8
en_CA.UTF-8
uk_UA.UTF-8
de_CH.ISO8859-15
de_DE.ISO8859-1
ca_ES
sr_YU
hy_AM.ARMSCII-8
ru_RU
zh_HK.UTF-8
eu_ES.ISO8859-1
is_IS
bg_BG.UTF-8
ja_JP.UTF-8
it_CH.ISO8859-15
fr_FR.UTF-8
ko_KR.UTF-8
et_EE.ISO8859-15
kk_KZ.UTF-8
ca_ES.ISO8859-15
en_IE.UTF-8
es_ES
de_CH.ISO8859-1
en_CA.ISO8859-1
es_ES.ISO8859-15
en_AU.ISO8859-1
el_GR
da_DK
no_NO
it_IT.ISO8859-1
en_IE
zh_HK.Big5HKSCS
hi_IN.ISCII-DEV
ja_JP.eucJP
it_IT.ISO8859-15
pl_PL
ko_KR.CP949
fr_CA.UTF-8
fi_FI.ISO8859-15
en_GB.ISO8859-15
fr_FR
hy_AM.UTF-8
no_NO.UTF-8
es_ES.UTF-8
de_AT
tr_TR.UTF-8
de_DE
lt_LT
tr_TR
C
POSIX

$ locale   
LANG="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_CTYPE="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=


Is LIKE (case sensitive) working as expected?

How about you whittle that down to the databases that are actually relevant to the question instead of just info dumping?

You have to create your database using a locale that recognizes that к is the lower case version of К. I recommend en_US.UTF-8 – that's not perfect for all languages, but a decent middle ground (and к is the lower case version of К).

I'm not sure if it's a well-thought-out answer. OP mentions “multilingual” app. We can't assume only Latin and Cyrillic and pick the “lowest common denominator”. There are plenty of other alphabets. At best, this answer lacks nuance.

@Greg True about the multilingual; I have changed the recommendation.
